# What is the name of this family of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Let $V$ be some finite set and let $V_0\subset V$ a nonempty subset. Let $G$ be the graph with vertices $V$ such that $\{i,j\}$ for $i\neq j\in V$ is an edge if and only if $\{i,j\}\cap V_0\neq\emptyset$.

Equivalently, such a graph is obtained from a star graph by replacing the center by a complete graph.

Is there a name for this family of graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called the [complete split graphs](https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1242.html).

This is motivated by the more general term "split graph": a graph whose vertex set $V$ can be partitioned into a disjoint union $A \cup B$ such that $A$ induces a clique and $B$ induces an independent set.

In the question, $A = V_0$ is a clique and $B = V - V_0$ is an independent set, so the graph is a split graph. Additionally, every edge between $A$ and $B$ is present, so the graph has as many edges as it could possibly have and still be a split graph with respect to the same partition. For this reason, we call it a *complete* split graph.

If $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, the complete split graph is also the complete $(n+1)$-partite graph $K_{m,1,1,\dots,1}$ (with $n$ $1$'s). This is obviously not a very good general notation, but if you're looking at a small case, it is an easy way to define the graph in terms of notation everyone will know.